# Create Team Project in TFS2013 in Team Web Access without Visual Studio

Tags: tfs

I would like to know if there is a possibility to create a team project in TFS2013 in the Web Interface without using Visual Studio. I would like to use TFS as general git repository platform. Visual Studio Online has such a possibility, but the menu does not exist in Team Web Access of the TFS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This option is not yet available in on-premise Team Foundation Server. Currently, its not possible to create a team project from web interface in on-premise instances.

Comment: Will it have this feature in TFS 2015?