# how to create a tfs project not by visual studio

Tags: tfs, project

I want to use tfs to manage our project and source code. But the visual studio is not needed, so how can I create a tfs project on the tfs server web portal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using visual studio because it's the easy way.

But if you're asking for else then you can use `tfpt CreateTeamProject` from [TFS Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f) with the appropriate version to your TFS server.

If you only like to create a Team Project from Web Access, then it is not available, which is answered in a SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23426885/create-team-project-in-tfs2013-in-team-web-access-without-visual-studio)